# FullCalendar 5 how to modify events created by rrule

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, rrule

I am struggling displaying the correct data from my database with FullCalendar. The database structure I've adopted is to store rrules as ReccurringEvent database objects, and individual deviations from those rrules as separate IndividualEvent objects, all of which have a "Done" property. The goal is to display each event's "Done" status individually even if they're all part of the same RRule.

ReccurringEvents are set up in FullCalendar as:

```js
calendar.addEvent({
  title: item['title'],
  rrule: { 
    dtstart: item['startDate'],
    freq: item['frequency']
  },
  allDay: item['allDay'],
  backgroundColor: backgroundRgb,
  textColor: computeTextColor(backgroundRgb),
  extendedProps: {
    recurringEventID: item['recurringEventID'],
    description: item['description']
  },
});
```

Then a separate javascript bit modifies those individual occurrences as "done" and attaches the appropriate IndividualEventID to the occurrence.

```js
var events = calendar.getEvents();
individualEventList.forEach(function(item){
  events.forEach(function(event){
    var indivdate = new Date(item['startDate']).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
    var eventdate = event.start.toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
    //if the event is on the correct date and is a part of the rrule...
    if(event.extendedProps.recurringEventID == item['recurringID'] && eventdate == indivdate)
    {
      console.log("match!");
      event.setExtendedProp('singleID',item['individualEventID'])
      //then modify its 'done' state
      event.setExtendedProp('done',item['done']);
    }
  })
})
```

The "match!" console log fires only once, as I am expecting, when I modify a single event instance to be done and then load my database in. However all events in the rrule show up as done when I click on them/investigate their extendedProps.

It seems that modifying one event's extendedProps will modify all events' extendedProps if they're in the same rrule. How do I control this behavior? Can I break an event out of its rrule? Do I need to just do this computation in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely avoid dealing with extendedProps that are per single event. What I ended up doing:

When a user clicks on the event and I want to render it as done or not, I will check that events recurringEventID extendedProp, then check all IndividualEventList events to see if there's one that came from the same recurring event, and then check that the dates match. Then I'll check an HTML checkbox based off of the IndividualEventList event's done state.

In other words, I'm completely bypassing using extendedProps for anything other than "tell me which recurring event the event that was clicked belongs to".

Since I am assuming that all events will be all-day events this will work for me, but it's not a very general solution.